# Regional usage of "guitarra" and "violão"

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas, vocabulário, música

When I was in Brazil, I learned to use the word *violão* to refer to an acoustic guitar, and *guitarra* to refer to an electric guitar.

However, according to [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/), *guitarra* has the following [definition](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/guitarra):

> 1. [Música]  Instrumento de cordas dedilhadas, com um braço dividido em semitons por filetes de metal. (Na guitarra eléctrica, os sons são captados por micros e ampliados.)

This seems to suggest that *guitarra* has both an acoustic and an electric version.

And [*violão*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/viol%C3%A3o):

> Viola grande, com seis cordas, das quais três são bordões.

Which leads to [*viola*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/viola):

> Instrumento musical análogo à guitarra, mas de sons mais baixos e com a caixa em forma de 8; banza.

This directly contrasts a *viola* (a small *violão*) to a *guitarra* (presumably an acoustic one).

Google doesn't clear up any confusion as a search for [*violão*](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=768&q=viol%C3%A3o&oq=viol%C3%A3o&gs_l=img.3..0l10.596.1986.0.2147.6.4.0.2.2.0.236.381.0j1j1.2.0....0...1ac.1j4.64.img..2.4.393.2Ucsg6FCR9M) shows images of acoustic guitars, and [*guitarra*](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=768&q=viol%C3%A3o&oq=viol%C3%A3o&gs_l=img.3..0l10.596.1986.0.2147.6.4.0.2.2.0.236.381.0j1j1.2.0....0...1ac.1j4.64.img..2.4.393.2Ucsg6FCR9M#tbm=isch&q=guitarra) shows both acoustic and electric guitars.

Clearly all of these words relate to various stringed instruments, where the strings may be plucked and/or played with a bow.  But what, specifically, do these words refer to regionally?

My best guess is that the vocabulary I learned is specific to Brazil, and that in Portugal the vocabulary may be somewhat different.

What do these words (*violão* and *guitarra*) refer to in Brazil and in Portugal (or any other regions of note)?  What is the best way to refer to the instruments represented by the English terms *guitar* and *electric guitar* (and for that matter, *violin*) in these regions?

Comment: on a note, if you are looking for the popular usage in brazil, viola is a specific kind of accoustic guitar (violão) and not just any smaller violão

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a Brazilian friend who plays the “violão.” Tried to entice him to come here and leave and answer, but to no use. So I’ll do my best with what he told me and my own research.

In theory ***guitarra*** is a very broad term that includes the ***violão***. See [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/guitarra) or [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=guitarra), which are more detailed than [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/guitarra). But in common usage it’s not so. Your best guess is correct. Basically in Brasil *guitarra* is an electric guitar, and *violão* an acoustic guitar; musically-educated people, as my friend, will tell between *violão acústico* (’acoustic guitar’), with metallic strings, and *violão cássico* (’classic guitar’), with nylon strings. In Portugal; everything is *guitarra*―*guitarra elétrica, guitarra acústica, guitarra clássica*.

The reason [*guitarra* in Google Images](https://www.google.pt/search?q=guitarra&num=50&as_st=y&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHiMGH4tvSAhXIhVQKHQTRDYwQ_AUICCgB&biw=1366&bih=662) returns both electric and acoustic guitars is that it mixes results from Brazil and Portugal. Select [“Brazil” in advanced search for *guitarra*](https://www.google.pt/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=guitarra&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgsz=&imgar=&imgc=&imgcolor=&imgtype=&cr=countryBR&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=), and about everything you get is electric guitars.

Now there’s a little twist. In Portugal, the classic and, I think, acoustic guitars are also known as ***viola***, especially in the context of fado and other traditional Portuguese music, where it will be played alongside the the unmistakably pear-shaped [*guitarra portuguesa* (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_guitar), pictured below on the right-hand side. [Listen to the guys if you like.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMFRAU2aOCI)

[image]
Listen to [this duo playing, left, “violão” (Brasil) or “guitarra” or “viola” (Portugal) and, right, “guitarra portuguesa”.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMFRAU2aOCI)

The detailed [Wikipédia article on *guitarra*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitarra) says that in Cabo Verde many musicians will call the classic guitar *violão*, and the acoustic guitar *viola*, but that laymen will use *viola* for everything.

But thechically  [*viola* (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=viola) can be either of two very different instruments. One is like a violin (and that is *violino* everywhere), but larger and with lower and deeper sounds. See [Wkipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola). It is *viola* in English too [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola). The other is like a small “violão”, and is popular in Brazilian and Portuguese rural music. It comes in many regional varieties, usually with their own individual names, such as [*viola caipira*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola_caipira) or [*viola beiroa*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violas_portuguesas#Viola_beiroa). See [“violas portuguesas” in Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violas_portuguesas), and [images of “violas brasileiras”](https://www.google.pt/search?espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=violas%20brasileiras&oq=violas%20brasileiras&gs_l=img.3...2859770.2861969.0.2862481.12.12.0.0.0.0.92.764.12.12.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.5.353...0j0i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i24k1j0i10i24k1.hSCx0QlYEtM) for more. You can see here [Fred Maciel explaining the difference between “violão” and “viola caipira.”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ErwsgZAmls) And listen to [this Dupla Sertaneja, pictured below, playing a “moda de viola antiga”:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wH1dD9tAdI)

[image]
[Dupla Sertaneja playing a “moda de viola antiga”, with “violão” (left) and “viola” (right).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wH1dD9tAdI)

Answer (score 4):

A Brazilian here.

I can't answer you about how it works in Portugal, but I can assure you that you can call an acoustic guitar as ***violão***. As for ***guitarra***, anyone here will think it is an electric guitar.

You should know that there's something we call *violão elétrico*, which is similar to an acoustic guitar with a plug to use in the sound hubs, but without an actual acoustic sound, only electric. But it ‘feels’ like an acoustic guitar. And there's the *violão eletroacústico*, which is the actual acoustic guitar with the plug for sound hub.

Hope this can help :)